# I am stuck in fixing compaitible jars in my spring boot kafka testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka

I am trying to to test my kafka consumer using EmbeddedKafka but seems to be in a compatibility issue
of jars as when I run my test it fails
I tried to change jar versions of related kafka libraries but was not able to find a combination which works

```
The following method did not exist:

    'java.util.Properties kafka.utils.TestUtils.createBrokerConfig(int, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean, int, scala.Option, scala.Option, scala.Option, boolean, boolean, int, boolean, int, boolean, int, scala.Option, int, boolean, int, short)'

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker and kafka.utils.TestUtils
```

This is my pom.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/-    maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.17</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>kafka-demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
        <avro.version>1.11.1</avro.version>
        <confluent.version>5.5.5</confluent.version>
          <kafka.version>3.4.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
              <version>3.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.rocksdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>rocksdbjni</artifactId>
            <version>6.29.4.1</version><!--The first version with support for Apple Silicon-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
             <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.3</version> <!--1.11.3-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.11.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
                            <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>kafka</id>
            <url>
                https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

did try to find the problematic jar I know its a compatibility issue of jars but not able to fix